# Copiar arquivo do computador local para o remoto via terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ssh

Existe alguma maneira de copiar um arquivo de uma pasta local para o uma remoto, através do terminal? Algo parecido com o comando `ssh`?

Answer (score 4):

Sim, utilizando o `scp`. Para sua documentação faça o comando no terminal `man scp` e veja mais em: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Answer (score 0):

Além do `scp`, `rsync` é uma excelente opção se o servidor tem o serviço SSH rodando e `rsync` também. Funciona não só para arquivos individuais.

```
$ rsync /pathlocal/arquivolocal usuario@servidor:/pathremoto/arquivoremoto
```

Uma terceira alternativa seria montar o endereço remoto, mapeando para um diretório local.